# How to login a user either by its username or email Id

Tags: php

i am making a login page in which i am using a mysql_query function which will check the combination of either:
username and password
OR
email and password

so for this i want to write a mysql query. Anyone who want to suggest this query:

```
mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(`user_id`) FROM `users` WHERE `username` = '$username_email' OR `email` = '$username_email' AND `password` = '$password'";
```

here how can i use OR, AND 
so that i can login a user.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to add parenthesis:

```
mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(user_id) FROM users WHERE (username = '$username_email' OR email = '$username_email') AND password = '$password'";);
```